# If condition issue while checking for empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting output in console like `{}`, Now I am checking it in if condition, it does not work

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data){
   if (data.length) {
        if(data.length === 0){
            $('.library_info_tbl tbody').prepend('<tr><td class="text-center centeralign" colspan="8">No Data Available!</td></tr>');
        }
        else{   
        }
    }
  });
```

If data contains `{}`, it does not check if condition i.e `if(data.length === 0)` does not work in the code.

Comment: `data` appears to be a plain object, not an array?

Comment: Arrays `[]` have a length property, objects `{}` don't (unless you added one yourself.)

Comment: sucess : function(response) { console.log(response.data) } //can you tell the output

Answer (score 2):

```
if (data.length) { ...... }
```

Above condition stops it from entering the inner block because 0 is treated as false, This the reason you are not able to execute your inner statement:

```
if(data.length === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
//if data is array 
if (data.length) {     
   $('.library_info_tbl tbody').prepend('<tr><td class="text-center centeralign" colspan="8">No Data Available!</td></tr>');
}
else 
{   
}

//if data is object

if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){//do something }
else{ }
```

Comment: if i write console,log(data); the output appears like {}

Comment: the above code does not work if(!data){//do something }
else{ }

Comment: `if (!data)` doesn't test for an empty object; even empty objects are truthy.

Comment: you are returning array or single object from your ajax method? @Nida

Comment: jQuery.isEmptyObject(data) this can be used to check empty object. I updated my answer. Try it @Nida

Answer (score 0):

Object in Javascript does not have a **length** property in their prototype.

If you are trying to find the length then first determine if it is an array or not.

```
success(result){
    if(result instanceof Array && result.length){ ... }
}
```

instanceof will determine if result is of type Array. Thus ensuring you can safely use length.

Hope it helps :-)